# Dealing with a dependent variable across multiple markets and time periods

Tags: time-series, multiple-regression, forecasting, arima

I am looking to forecast rents across several markets. I have time series data going back 15 years for 4 different markets. I also have variables that I expect to correlate with Supply and Demand and am hoping to include them as independant variables.

The model I am looking to run is roughly

$rent_{it} = \beta_0+\beta_1demand_{it}+\beta_2supply_{it}$

where $i=market$.

I have attempted running arima models by each market (four separate regressions) but I seriously doubt this is the best way to approach the problem.

I feel I am leaving a lot of data unused by running a series of regressions instead of using all data in one model.

**Is there an appropriate model or technique that will allow me to include all rent, supply and demand data across markets in a single model?**

Also, I am using R for this analysis.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is a typical **panel data** because you have multiple time measurements of the same few objects. Therefore you may consider **panel analysis (regression)** statistical models.